# Odata Routing for reference operations, lack of documentation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net-core, odata

I have a problem getting link creation and deletion working against a controller using Odata 7.0.1

According to http://odata.github.io/WebApi/#03-01-routing-abstract the following emplates should automatically create routes (Section Querying, Creating and Deleting Links)

Http POST and PUT on a method named `CreateRef`

Further down the method signature on the controller is shown as

```
// POST /odata/Products(1)/Supplier/$ref
public HttpResponseMessage CreateLink(int key, string navigationProperty, [FromBody] Uri link)
```

For deletes it is:

```
// DELETE /odata/Products(1)/Supplier/$ref
public HttpResponseMessage DeleteLink(int key, string navigationProperty, [FromBody] Uri link)
```

with the template being

`HTTP DELETE DeleteRef`

I have a client integration test and it generates a link in the form

`DELETE http://localhost/Building(007c3552-43da-44c4-bf8f-b5221553c484)/UsageTypes/$ref?$id=UsageType(18)`

which looks good to me.

Sadly I always get a routing error, a WebRequestException "not found".

I tried both

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteRef(Guid key, String navigationProperty, [FromBody] Uri link) {
    return Ok();
}
```

and

```
[HttpDelete]
public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteLink(Guid key, String navigationProperty, [FromBody] Uri link) {
    return Ok();
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Note that Odata in general works - we have get and put and post methods for individual objects, functions and actions properly generated for routing. For now, only links seem to fail (which are a new part we now put into production to retire an old REST based API).

Comment: Have you tried to use the GET request first? There is an example under the section "Sample for Delta Feed". I never used links in OData and I am trying to figure out if you have to enable it in the initial OData onfiguration where you white-list the supported operations.

Comment: In your delete request what body do you send along with the request? the link is using [FromBody]